# Django: Fields of DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass (without instance)

Tags: python, django

I try to discover the fields which a django form class has.

I only have a class, not an instance.

The form-class is of type `DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass`.

If I try this:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    spreadsheet = forms.FileField()

for field in FooForm:
    print(field)
```

I get this exception:

```
TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable
```

I know that I could do FooForm() instead of FooForm, but in my real use case I only have a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access `FooForm.base_fields`.